# Reference for mathematical time-independent perturbation theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, hamiltonian, perturbation-theory, eigenvalue

I was wondering if anyone knew of a reference which treat time-independent [perturbation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_(quantum_mechanics)) in a mathematical fashion. All of the mathematical textbooks in quantum mechanics that I know of do not treat this subject. I am hoping that such a reference would treat:

1. Perturbation theory of the pure point spectrum in a more systematic way than physics textbooks do. It seems to me that by using appropriate notation one should be able to give a clear account of degenerate perturbation theory in all orders.
2. Perturbation theory of the continuous and residual spectrum. In particular, is it possible to give a unified account of all of the spectrum as a whole.